# Passing session variables from html form to multiple php page urls?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to pass variables from the form to multiple pages in php

The form "rentcheck.php"

```
<?php require ("Connections/Project.php") ;?>
<?php session_start();?>

<title>Rent Check</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="rent.php">
  <table width="385" height="70" border="1">
    <tr>
    <td><label for="select3">Select Customer</label>
      <select name="Customer_ID" id="Customer_ID">
        <?php
//Select from SQL Database Table (t_customer)

        $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * from t_customer");

        while ($Customer = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
         echo "<option value='".$Customer['Customer_ID']."'>".$Customer['Customer_Name']."</option>";
        }
          ?>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
</table>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

After input and Pass it to page "rent.php"

```
<?php
require("Connections/Project.php");


//$_SESSION['yourvariable'] = 'foo';

//$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row_Recordset1['Customer_CC_Exp_Date']));
session_start();
$datetoday=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$endOfCycle=date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+30 days"));
if(isset($_GET['page'])){


    $pages=array("products","cart");

    if(in_array($_GET['page'], $pages)){

        $_page=$_GET['page'];


    }else{
        $_page="products";
    }

}else{
    $_page="products";

}
?>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Rent</title>
</head>
<body>
<p> <?php require($_page. ".php");?>
<?php echo $_POST['Customer_ID'];?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

This page (rent.php) shows the value from the form.

And the third page "products.php"

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>



<?php

if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=="add"){


    $custget=$_SESSION['Customer_ID'];
    $id=intval($_GET['id']);

    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id][$custget])){

        $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity']++;
        $getcust=$_SESSION['Customer_ID'];

    }else{
        $sql_s="SELECT * FROM t_dvd_copy
        WHERE dvd_copy_id={$id}";
        $query_s=mysql_query($sql_s);
        if(mysql_num_rows($query_s)!=0){
            $row_s=mysql_fetch_array($query_s);

            $_SESSION['cart'][$row_s['dvd_copy_id']]=array(
            "quantity" =>1,
            "price" => $row_s['price']
            );


        }else{
            $message="NO";

        }
    }
}
?>

<?php if(isset($message)) {
    echo"$message"; }
    //echo print_r($_SESSION['cart']); ?>

<table width="489" height="52" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="123">DVD Copy ID</td>
    <td width="120">Name</td>
    <td width="91">Price</td>
    <td width="127">Action</td>
  </tr>


 <?php
        $sql="SELECT *, dvd_title FROM t_dvd_copy INNER JOIN t_dvd ORDER BY dvd_title ASC";
        $query=mysql_query($sql);

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['dvd_copy_id']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['dvd_title']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['price']?></td>
        <td><a href="rent.php?page=products&action=add&id=<?php echo $row['dvd_copy_id']?>">Add To Cart</a></td>
<?php
        }
    ?>

</table>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This page (products.php) shows:

> Notice: Undefined index: Customer_ID in C:\xampp\htdocs\project3\rent.php on line 39" whenever I clicked the "Add to Cart" or manually type "rent.php?=cart".

I'm trying to do is to show(Customer_ID)/pass the variables on multiple pages("products.php","cart.php").

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Make sure `session_start()` is at the top of every page using sessions before any output.

Comment: Your products.php page doesn't have `session_start();` See John's comment.

Comment: It shows "Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\project3\products.php on line 10"

Comment: Then try adding `ob_start();` under your opening `<?php` tags. Sometimes that helps. If not, then just do this. `<?php session_start(); ?>` at the top of all your files followed by the rest of your code, and remove `session_start();` where you have it now. That should take care of the errors. You have it now, but under `<?php require ("Connections/Project.php") ;?>` place it above that.

Comment: Still no luck. And the same error (Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\project3\products.php on line 1). Thank you for your reply

Comment: Make sure there are no spaces or HTML etc. before your `<?php` opening tag and files are saved as UTF-8 "without" BOM. @Escii

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you have not started the session on the other pages. 
on every php page that you want to have a session you need to put `session_start();` at the top.

if you don't the session will end and empty all the data from it.

if you want to make sure what is in your session you can print it out like so:

```
echo "<pre>";
echo print_r($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1. You mentioned that when you clicked "Add to Cart" it didn't work. I assume you mean the button labelled "Submit" on the rentcheck.php page. Can you confirm this is right please?
2. You would get an error when manually navigating to rent.php?=cart as you are looking for a `Customer_ID` key in the `$_POST` array but at this point you are not posting to the server, you are performing a `$_GET` request.
3. You have referenced `$_SESSION['Customer_ID']` but I cannot see in your code where you have set this (products.php 7th line of code).

I would suggest thinking through how a user might navigate through your website:

- where are they likely to start?
- what variables will be available to you at this point?
- what will you do if the required variables do not exist (e.g. `$_SESSION`)?
- what is the earliest point you can collect the required information (your form)?
- once the form has been completed correctly, how can I make sure that the required information is retained throughout the users session?
- have I continued to test on each page that my required variables are available to me?

Start with that and see where it leads you.

Comment: 1. The "Add to Cart" is the button in products.php page. (<td><a href="rent.php?page=products&action=add&id=<?php echo $row['dvd_copy_id']?>">Add To Cart</a></td>)
2.I'm taking a look about that
3.The Customer_ID set from the form page(rentcheck.php)

Comment: 1. Your issue is the `$_POST` array. The Add to Cart link performs a GET request not a POST.
3. I can't see `$_SESSION['Customer_ID'] = $_POST['Customer_ID']` which is what I would expect to set the session variable.

Comment: I changed all the array to GET and the html form to get also. I set the session variable $_SESSION['Customer_ID'] = $_GET['Customer_ID']. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code I can see that you are including `products.php` inside `rent.php`

So a couple of thoughts here:

- products.php should not have HTML `<head>` because it will be rendered
  inside the `<body>`
- If you have a variable available in rent.php it will be available
  under the same name in products.php.

So if you have in `rent.php`:

```php
$customer_id = $_POST['Customer_ID'];
require('products.php');
```

In `products.php` you can use `$customer_id` directly.

Comment: Still, it's the same error (Undefined index: Customer_ID).
Except I Used $customer_id = $_GET['Customer_ID']; instead of $_POST, in order to match the arrays from form to products.

Comment: Your form in rentcheck.php is using `method="post"` so `Customer_ID` will be in `$_POST` not `$_GET`